# Calculating set difference in arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a C program with many functions. For one of the functions, I need to be able to calculate the set difference, find out which elements are located in set A but NOT in set B, and store them in a new set.

This is what I have so far. It calculates it right for the most part, but for some reason the new array has the numbers that ARE in both first, and THEN the ones that are only in set A and not set B. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
// set_difference takes all numbers in set a BUT NOT in set b and puts them in set c
void set_difference(int a[], int b[], int c[]) {
    for(int i=1; i<=a[0]; i++) {
        if(element_of(a[i], b) == FALSE) {
            enter_set(a[i], c);
        }
    }
} // set A: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  // set B: [3, 4, 5, 6]
  //output in new array: [3, 4, 1, 2]
  // DESIRED output: [1, 2]
```

Here is the element_of function that you see being called:

```
int element_of(int v, int a[]) {
   int i;
   for(i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++)
        if ( a[i] == v) return TRUE;
   return FALSE;
}
```

And here is the enter_set function:

```
void enter_set(int v, int a[]) {

   if(a[0] == MAX_SET_SIZE)
    printf("Max set size exceeded\n");
   else if (!element_of(v, a)){  //calls element_of function to determine an element is already in the set
    a[0]++;
        a[a[0]]=v;
   }
}
```

And here is how I am calling set_difference:

```
set_difference(a, b, c); // a, b, and c are populated using scanf
printf("Set difference of A and B: ");
print_set(c);
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Set C : [1, 2]. Is it right?

Comment: Please show `enter_set`, how you print out `c` and how you call `set_difference`.

Comment: My first suspect would be that the array c needs to be cleared probably by setting c[0] to zero and then as you add items to the array, increment c[0] so that you know how many items are in the array and you use the value of c[0] as the array index. I assume that `enter_set()` operates by using the first or zeroth array element as the one based index into the array as well as the count of total number of array entries?

Comment: Where and how is `c` declared? In particular, where and how is `c[0]` initialised? Because `c[0]` is not intialised anywhere in your code and it probably needs to be within `set_difference`.

Comment: Please read how and why it is good to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will save a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: @AlanAu simply initializing c[0] = 0 in the first line of the set_difference function seemed to work. Why is that the case?

Comment: Ho, ho, ho.  I have made the same mistake myself many times.

Comment: Because that's the way you have designed your code. The zero-th element is the number of elements in the array. `c` is the result array that you continuously add to. So of course the number of elements in `c` needs to be set to 0 before starting to add in the results.

Comment: if I were you I would use `if(a[0] >= MAX_SET_SIZE)` rather than the equality just to make sure that if something else modifies `a[0]` you will still catch the size.  I assume that you dimension `a` to `MAX_SET_SIZE + 1` as in `int a[MAX_SET_SET + 1];`?  Also looks like you could be calling function `element_of()` twice, once when doing a check to see if it is in the set and then again when adding it to the set.  Not sure why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented the missing parts of the code and it is working just fine. Note that this implementation will not add to the set those elements that are present in B and not in A. Here is the working example.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[5] = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b[5] = {5, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int c[5 + 5] = {0};
    set_difference(a, b, c);
    for(i = 1; i <= c[0]; ++i)
        printf("%d, ", c[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void set_difference(int a[], int b[], int c[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=a[0]; i++){
        if(element_of(a[i], b) == FALSE)
            enter_set(a[i], c);
    }
}

int element_of(int v, int a[])
{
   int i;
   for(i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++){
        if ( a[i] == v)
            return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}

void enter_set(int value, int a[])
{
    ++a[0];
    a[a[0]] = value;
}
```

The only remaining code that could cause a problem is the input and output of those arrays, so maybe look at them again.